# How to lock file in SVN without working copy?

Tags: svn

Is it possible to lock and unlock a file in SVN without working copy, like other SVN operations mentioned in [Working Without a Working Copy](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.working-without-a-wc.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lock a file directly by passing the file's URL. Here is an example:

```
svn lock https://svn.example.com/svn/MyRepo/trunk/myfile.bmp -m "My Lock Message"
```